# Duplicate elements of a list on even index

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, how do I implement a function `dup` that duplicates all elements that are on even positions (0,2,4...) in a list

```
dup :: [a] -> [a]
dup [] = []
dup (x:xs) =  x : x : dup xs
//but only on even index ??
```

Example of call:

```
dup [1,5,2,8,4] = [1,1,5,2,2,8,4,4]
```

Comment: By writing a function definition for `dup`. Any attempt from your side?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added what I have tried

Comment: Use pattern matching so you address two elements at a time: `dup (x:y:xs) = x:x:y:dup xs`. If `x` has an even index according to you, then `y` must have an odd index, and you're left with the base cases of lists containing zero or one element in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well we can define two functions that perform *mutual recursion*: `dupeven :: [a] -> [a]` and `dupodd :: [a] -> [a]`. `dupeven` thus will duplicate the first element, and the pass recursively to `dupodd`. `dupodd` on the other hand only makes one copy of the head, and then perform recursion on `dupeven`. Like:

```
dupeven :: [a] -> [a]
dupeven [] = []
dupeven (x:xs) = x : x : dupodd xs

dupodd :: [a] -> [a]
dupodd [] = []
dupodd (x:xs) = x : dupeven xs
```

The nice thing is that we get two dupplicate variants. Furthermore both functions are rather simple: they only operate on two different patterns the empty list `[]` and the "cons" `(:)`.

This thus works as expected, and furthermore we basically have an extra function at (rather) low implementation cost:

```
Prelude> dupeven [1,5,2,8,4]
[1,1,5,2,2,8,4,4]
Prelude> dupodd [1,5,2,8,4]
[1,5,5,2,8,8,4]
```

Answer (score 4):

As other answers explain, you can write this function recursively from first principles, but I always think problems like these are interesting puzzles: *how can you compose such a function from the existing base library?*

First, whenever you want to index a list, you can `zip` it with a lazily evaluated infinite list:

```
Prelude> zip [0..] [1,5,2,8,4]
[(0,1),(1,5),(2,2),(3,8),(4,4)]
```

In this case, though, you don't really need to know the actual index values (`0, 1, 2, 3, 4` and so on). Instead, you just need to know how many repetitions of each number you need. You can produce that knowledge by infinitely cycling through `2` and `1`:

```
Prelude> take 10 $ cycle [2,1]
[2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
```

(The above example uses `take 10` to stop evaluation of the list, which, otherwise, continues forever.)

You can `zip (cycle [2,1])` with any input list to get a list of tuples:

```
Prelude> zip (cycle [2,1]) [1,5,2,8,4]
[(2,1),(1,5),(2,2),(1,8),(2,4)]
```

The first element of the tuple is how many times to repeat the second element.

You can use `replicate` to repeat any value a number of times, but you'll have to `uncurry` it to take a single tuple as input:

```
Prelude> uncurry replicate (2,1)
[1,1]
Prelude> uncurry replicate (1,5)
[5]
```

Notice that this function always returns a list, so if you do this over a list of tuples, you'll have a list of lists. To immediately flatten such a list, you can therefore use monadic bind to flatten the projection:

```
Prelude> zip (cycle [2,1]) [1,5,2,8,4] >>= uncurry replicate
[1,1,5,2,2,8,4,4]
```

You can, if you will, make a function out of it:

```
dup xs = zip (cycle [2,1]) xs >>= uncurry replicate
```

This function turns out to be parametrically polymorphic, so while you can use it with lists of integers, you can also use it with lists of characters:

```
Prelude> dup [1,5,2,8,4]
[1,1,5,2,2,8,4,4]
Prelude> dup "acen"
"aaceen"
```

Comment: I really like the pedagogical approach taken in this answer. Only one minor suggestion: rather than producing and immediately consuming a tuple, consider `zipWith replicate`. Then, since you've already done the work, on the other side of the `>>=` you can do nothing with `id`. (Or specialize `foo >>= id` to `concat foo`, which is likely more readable for beginners and experts alike.) My final form would therefore be `dup = concat . zipWith replicate (cycle [2,1])`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make a mutually recursive set of functions

```
duplicate, duplicate' :: [a] -> [a]
duplicate [] = []
duplicate (x:xs) =  x : x : duplicate' xs
duplicate' [] = []
duplicate' (x:xs) = x : duplicate xs
```

Or add a simple ADT to determine the next action

```
data N = O | T
duplicate = duplicate' T
duplicate' _ [] = []
duplicate' T (x:xs) = x : x : duplicate' O xs
duplicate' O (x:xs) = x : duplicate' T xs
```

But in all honesty, the best way of doing it is what @Simon_Shine suggested,

```
duplicate [] = []
duplicate (x:y:xs) = x : x : y : duplicate xs
duplicate (x:xs) = x : x : xs -- Here x is an even index and xs is an empty list
```